# Initially I have shuffled the array elements, how do I sort these elements?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Initially I have shuffled the array elements. Now how do I sort these array elements in a definite order. This is for the purpose of a card game in iOS.

Comment: You are not showing your efforts. Show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array using `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`

```
[cards sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    Card *c1 = (Card *)obj1;
    Card *c2 = (Card *)obj2;

    if (c1.value == c2.value) return NSOrderedSame;
    return (c1.value > c2.value) ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedAscending;
}];
```

Comment: This does not look correct. Your comparator does not return `NSOrderedAscending (-1)` if "c1 < c2".

Comment: Cheers @MartinR. Still half asleep this morning. Updated the answer.

Comment: @neilco i will give an idea of how my array is. there is a main array holding 52 cards. then i created four subarrays as i have four players.before distributing cards to each player main array is shuffled

Comment: @user2963228 Pertinent information like this should _always_ be included in the original question. What do you want sorting—the main array or the four player arrays?

Comment: @neilco four players array

Comment: sorry that i didn't include these in question.

Comment: Use the code above on each of the player arrays.

Comment: @neilco [cards sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)   here i hope cards that you meant is array and the Cards is the class name

Comment: `cards` is plural and refers to an array. `Card` is singular and refers to a class that describes the properties of a playing card, including its suit and face value.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options, you can check NSArray documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12) and look under 'Sorting'.

For quick info, you can use NSSortDescriptors

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [shuffledArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

they are easy to use, and you can add multiple sort descriptors.
You can also use comparators

```
[sortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    // Do your check here and return values below
    // NSOrderedSame
    // NSOrderedDescending
    // NSOrderedAscending
}];
```

Edit:

Okay, from what I understand from comments below is that you an array with cards that is shuffled initially.

```
NSArray *shuffledCards
```

I guess you have Card objects inside that array. If you don't, i think you should. And then there are four players. And again I believe you have Player objects.

For the sake of example:

```
@interface Card : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger cardNumber;
@end

@interface Player : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic) NSArray *dealtCards;
@end
```

Let's say you select 10 random cards from the shuffled array and dealt them to each player.

```
NSArray *randomTenCards = // You get 10 cards somehow

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cardNumber" ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortedCards = [randomTenCards sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

// The Card objects are now sorted inside sortedCards array according to their cardNumbers.

[self.player1 setDealtCards:sortedCards];
...
...
```

The basic idea is like that. You can adjust this to your own problem i hope.

Comment: I have tried this nssortdescriptor but my concern is it only possible only with array with dictionaries?

Comment: what would i give in the place of sortDescriptorWithKey if using arrays of arrays

Comment: You can use sort descriptors with custom objects as well. It doesn't have to be array of dictionaries. You just give the objects property name as the key parameter. If you have complex structures inside your array, you may be better of using comparator. Since i haven't seen your array or objects, I can't give a clear suggestion on that.

Comment: i will give an idea of how my array is. there is a main array holding 52 cards. then i created four subarrays as i have four players.before distributing cards to each player main array is shuffled. @mrt

Comment: @user2963228: It would be more helpful if you add the relevant information to the *question* instead of "hiding" it in the comments.

Comment: @MartinR sorry that i didn't include these in question

Comment: and i guess you want the cards inside player arrays to be sorted? Why don't you just sort player arrays individually? Maybe you should edit your question to give more detail, so others can also give their suggestions.

Comment: @mrt  i want to sort each player arrays individually.

Comment: @mrt my class uiviewcontroller not nsobject...is it possible to declare property

Comment: @mrt it is breaking at this  NSArray * sortedCards = [User_cards sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]]; line of code

Comment: @mrt can you please respond to my question

Comment: make sure you are using the correct name as the key of the descriptor. A property with the same name should exists on the object. You should check the class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html . If its not a comparable property, there are other options with comparators. Just check the documentations.

Comment: @mrt is it because my class is not nsobject ?

Comment: @mrt is it because my class is not nsobject ?

Comment: @MartinR is it not possible to use sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) for two-dimensional nsmutable array?? coz when i tried it for single dimensional NSArray it works fine.

Comment: @user2963228: I can't find the relevant information in your *question* yet: What does your array look like? What kind of objects does it contain? How should the objects be sorted? What result do you expect? What did you try? .....

Comment: @MartinR array here is nsmutable array and it contains image name and card number... this array is shuffled and then passed to each player array.. so it must be like this for e.g. spade1,club5,heart10,diamond2...after sorting it shud look like club5,diamond2,heart10,spade1